# Push Notifications using Service Workers and CRA 2.0

Tags: reactjs, caching, push-notification, service-worker

I'm struggling to find a way to add web push notifications from a server to the CRA service worker. Does anyone have experience with this? Bonus points if it's through the new CRA 2.0 SW.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: i think this might help! https://hackernoon.com/integrating-push-notifications-in-your-react-web-app-cra-22d3010392e